# jQuery .attr wont change second time

Tags: jquery

this dont work.. it change the id to trigger but when i click again nothing happens..

my html

```
<a id="love"><i class="favorite love material-icons medium ">favorite</i></a>
```

```js
$("#love").click(function() {


  $("#love").attr("id", "trigger");


});

$("#trigger").unbind("click").click(function() {

  $("#trigger").attr("id", "love");
});
```

Hope somebody can help me :3

Comment: This might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to change the id in the first place? The listener is attached to the element itself. Changing the id doesn't change the reference to that specific element object. The listener is still there after you change the id

Comment: you want really the click our touchstart  and touchend event?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you're trying to achieve here. You're binding the click event to `#love` and when clicked that should change the id of that element to something else, only then you're going to have an element with that id.

Your code runs the first bind and then tries to run the second one but that won't work because `#trigger` doesn't exist yet.

The best way to do what you're trying to do here is this:

```js
function bindLove() {
  $("#love").off("click").click(function() {
    $("#love").attr("id", "trigger");
    bindTrigger();
  });
}

function bindTrigger() {
  $("#trigger").off("click").click(function() {
    $("#trigger").attr("id", "love");
    bindLove();
  });
}

bindLove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="love">
  Change ID
</button>
```

But this is really weird.

Comment: unbind is deprecated